# Why the link get from youtube get_video_info doesn't work for download?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-dl

I test with browser with the link I get from "http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=xx" to see if it is be able to download.

After remove some parameters from original link, some works but some still don't. 
I read some post here but most of are pretty old. A lot of change since then.
I wonder if there are somebody working on this recently.

The purpose I need this is because my youtube view program need a better quality video to display.

This is link doesn't work:

http://r17---sn-tt17rn7e.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?fexp=902529%2C932000%2C906383%2C902000%2C919512%2C929903%2C931202%2C900821%2C900823%2C931203%2C931401%2C908529%2C919373%2C930803%2C906836%2C920201%2C929602%2C930101%2C930603%2C900824%2C910223&ipbits=8&expire=1364854787&sver=3&mt=1364829200&newshard=yes&id=26c94a41dba396f5&key=yt1&upn=GrcnDUPfreQ&cp=U0hVSVhQUl9NUUNONV9QSlZIOm9BbnVkMTJzOXE5&sparams=algorithm%2Cburst%2Ccp%2Cfactor%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&ip=173.248.214.165&itag=34&ms=au&source=youtube&mv=m&signature=9593596F58B377FAA4C8F5A4516C7F53CE473340.507CA2EA250CEED2E2B2377FD70EE1A0478EE322&type=video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2"&itag=18&

What wrong with it? I removed fallback_path and replace sig with signature.
The working link is for webm. This is for h264. Both have the same kind of parameters.

And this is working now.
http://r17---sn-tt17rn7e.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?fexp=909708%2C912514%2C930802%2C932400%2C916624%2C931009%2C932000%2C906383%2C902000%2C919512%2C929903%2C931202%2C900821%2C900823%2C931203%2C931401%2C908529%2C930807%2C919373%2C906836%2C920201%2C929602%2C930101%2C930603%2C900824%2C910223&ms=au&itag=44&mt=1364825784&ipbits=8&cp=U0hVSVhQT19NUUNONV9QSlNCOlp5ZGoyMXJ3emlq&ip=173.248.214.165&upn=ohH0s8EjPyo&newshard=yes&source=youtube&ratebypass=yes&mv=m&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&id=26c94a41dba396f5&expire=1364851187&key=yt1&sver=3&signature=798EED35782B846D2B0EA190A17E837A0DBA18EA.AD56BCF6365AAD974C18F09F352F9422084C50AC&type=video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"&quality=large,itag=35&

Answer (score -1):

That's not a supported method of interacting with YouTube. You need to use one of the official [YouTube Player mechanisms](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#player_apis) to display YouTube videos.

Please familiarize yourself with the [YouTube API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I am using gdata api to get the link for video but it only provide low quality 3gpp 176x144. How to get at least 320x240 h264 quality video? format query parameter doesn't support "18" what I need. Any idea?

Comment: You need to use one of the official playback mechanisms to gain access to higher resolution video.

Comment: I did a google and didn't find what is the official playback mechanisms. I would more than like to use if there is. Do you have link for that solution?

Comment: I linked to it in my response: https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#player_apis

Comment: Thanks! I read this part from very beginning of my development. I didn't get it because it seems for javascript. Will it use browser's player or use the lib from youtube. I don't use javascript and know very limited about them. I use java and C++ on android.

Comment: If you're doing Android development, this Player library is your best bet: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: Yes, I already tested it before. It looks good. I didn't use it for a few reasons. It seems take video id and then do everything by itself. I rarely be able to know and control. It use fragment which doesn't support android-support-v4 library which I am using. I can't use activity of it directly. And it has developer key required and limited by quota of 10,000 clicks per day. Will users get refused after that number or somebody need pay for more? I don't know. The most important is I need to support more than Youtube. I need use a general media player for that purpose.

Comment: Downvoted because while this isn't an officially supported way of doing this, *there is no officially supported way of doing this on many platforms, therefore we need to use unofficial solutions*.

Comment: As it's officially not supported, we are getting issue now, the answer is valid, so Upvoting